# MS Dynamics CRM. Workflow update record

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have workflow that updates entity record after checking condition. Everything works well. But... For example workflow's owner is User1 and i try to modify the record with User2. I thought field "Modified By" must have a value User2, but it has a value User1. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic workflows inside Dynamics CRM always run in the security context of the owner of the workflow.

In your case the owner of the workflow is User1, so it's right that the modifiedby field has User1 value.

To complete the answer, on-demand workflows run in the security context of the running user.